# Why I can not install SQL Server Express 2016 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit SP1?

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2

There was a need to upgrade SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2016 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit, so when I started the installation of SQL Server 2061 Express SP2 using

```
SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe
```

on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit SP1 there was a note on the first window:

> Note: your Operating System is not supported by SQL Server 2016.
>   You may download the installation media but you will not be able to install it on this machine. For more information see this link:
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=826321

[image]

What can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

The error is telling you the problem, Windows Server 2008 is not supported by Microsoft SQL Server 2016. As per [Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server - Processor, Memory, and Operating System Requirements: Principal Editions of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016#TOP_Principal), SQL Server 2016 can be installed on:

> SQL Server Enterprise:
>
> - Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2019 Standard
> - Windows Server 2019 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2016 Standard
> - Windows Server 2016 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
>
> SQL Server Standard:
>
> - Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2019 Standard
> - Windows Server 2019 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2016 Standard
> - Windows Server 2016 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
>
> SQL Server Developer:
>
> - Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2019 Standard
> - Windows Server 2019 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2016 Standard
> - Windows Server 2016 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
> - Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 Foundation
> - Windows 10 Home
> - Windows 10 Professional
> - Windows 10 Enterprise
> - Windows 10 IoT Enterprise
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8.1 Pro
> - Windows 8.1 Enterprise
> - Windows 8
> - Windows 8 Pro
> - Windows 8 Enterprise
>
> SQL Server Express:
>
> - Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2019 Standard
> - Windows Server 2019 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2016 Standard
> - Windows Server 2016 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
> - Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 Foundation
> - Windows 10 Home
> - Windows 10 Professional
> - Windows 10 Enterprise
> - Windows 10 IoT Enterprise
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8.1 Pro
> - Windows 8.1 Enterprise
> - Windows 8
> - Windows 8 Pro
> - Windows 8 Enterprise
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
> - Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 Foundation
> - Windows 10 Home
> - Windows 10 Professional
> - Windows 10 Enterprise
> - Windows 10 IoT Enterprise
> - Windows 8.1
> - Windows 8.1 Pro
> - Windows 8.1 Enterprise
> - Windows 8
> - Windows 8 Pro
> - Windows 8 Enterprise
> - Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2012 Standard
> - Windows Server 2012 Essentials
> - Windows Server 2012 Foundation

Windows Server 2008 (R2) is not one of those Operating systems.

In truth, this is another reason you should be upgrading. Windows Server 2008 (R2) support runs out on January 14, 2020, that's only 7 months away. You should be looking at changing now, so that you can iron out any kinks before you move your production server.

Comment: I've downloaded the installtion package from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56840 , where Windows server 2008 R2 was in supported OS list

Comment: I'd suggest that's wrong @Avrob (in fact, this shows it to be). As far as I recall, 2016 never supported 2008/Windows 7 (I remember not being able to install the preview on my old Windows 7 PC at the office). If you need to check what versions of Windows a product supports, I would always suggest check the documentation, not the details on the download.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like SQL Server Express 2016 isn't supported in Windows Server 2008  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016

You'll either have to upgrade your windows OS, or keep your current SQL Server version.

Below is a list of windows OS' that can support SQL Server Express 2016.

```
SQL Server Express  Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

Windows Server 2019 Standard

Windows Server 2019 Essentials

Windows Server 2016 Datacenter

Windows Server 2016 Standard

Windows Server 2016 Essentials

Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter

Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials

Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation

Windows Server 2012 Datacenter

Windows Server 2012 Standard

Windows Server 2012 Essentials

Windows Server 2012 Foundation

Windows 10 Home

Windows 10 Professional

Windows 10 Enterprise

Windows 10 IoT Enterprise

Windows 8.1

Windows 8.1 Pro

Windows 8.1 Enterprise

Windows 8

Windows 8 Pro

Windows 8 Enterprise
```

Comment: I've downloaded the installtion package from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56840 , where Windows server 2008 R2 was in supported OS list.

Comment: Like I said under my answer, the documentation, @Avrob . And the fact that you're experiencing this problem proves the point further.

Comment: From your original description, it appears the link you downloaded from is wrong.  That’s why you got the OS is not supported error message.